# Can I use $\partial$ as a shorthand for the partial derivative?

Tags: notation, partial-derivative

For example, $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ might be written as $\partial_x f$. Is there any conflict with existing notation?

Comment: I have seen $D_x f$ more often, but wikipedia lists both $\partial_x f$ and $D_x f$ (among other options), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative and also http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/273/lessons/l1103.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $\partial_x f$ is a fairly well-understood notation, in my experience.

Using just $\partial f$ (in the context of differentiating a function) is vague however (which variable are you differentiating w.r.t.?), so be sure to be clear.

Comment: In convex geometry, $\partial f$ stands for the [subderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative) of $f$. So this notation $\partial f$ on its own is actually a thing too, but again it all relies on the magic word: context.

Comment: True, I suppose. Plus I also see $\partial A$ to denote the boundary of $A$ (though using a lowercase letter is infrequent) -- so yeah, context is definitely important. Though in the context of differentiating a function, it's vague.